# Explorer column handler shell extension sort function c#

Tags: c#, shell, dom, sorting, handler

I am trying to create a date sent column handler for .eml files for Windows XP. Using [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3747/Explorer-column-handler-shell-extension-in-C) I can create the column but I do not know how to implement custom sort functionality.

Can someone tell me if a custom sort function is possible, and the best way to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you have already read [this - Don't do Shell Extension Handlers in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx)

Comment: I can go as far as to say that it is, because I played with the equivalent code in VB6 a long time ago, and remember doing it. I don't remember the details (except that I found childish humour in the name `SHITEMID`, which is a Windows structure that was involved), and it was a very different language with different interop, but the basic functionality is definitely something that can be tapped into.

Comment: @L.B "Another notable improvement is side-by-side (SxS) support for multiple versions of .NET.  This allows hosting of more than one version of the CLR within a single process.  This makes writing shell extensions, for example, in C# a reality in .NET 4.0.  You shouldn't need to target .NET 4.0, but as long as .NET 4.0 is installed you should be able to write shell extensions in a current version of .NET (like .NET 2.0) and it will be supported." http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/11/12/net-4-0-evolving-net-development.aspx

Comment: @Jon Hanna Thanks, any idea of where to find the desired COM Interfaces? I have very little experience with COM and C#. I'm basically making loosely educated guesses at this point.

Comment: I was mostly working from http://amzn.to/RT1F9p which doesn't seem to even be in print. Maybe O'Reilly Digital have it. There must be better resources out there, but I'm not the person to tell you about them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. The shell passes a `SHCOLUMNINIT` struct into Initialize(). One of the `SHCOLUMNINIT` members is `csFlags`. If this is set to `SHCOLSTATE_TYPE_DATE` the column data will be treated as a date. The constants definitions can be viewed here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)